# How to get the manipulated image as a resource from CodeIgniter's `image_lib`?

Tags: php, codeigniter, imagemagick, gd, image-manipulation

We're working on a script that draws multiple images on a canvas, after manipulating each of them separately, i.e. resize + rotate.

The canvas is an image resource, which we need to copy the manipulated images to. In order to achieve this, my only thought is using PHP's `imagecopy` function, which requires that the image being copied be a resource too. So, how can I obtain the manipulated image from `image_lib` as a resource?

Comment: I think you just set a "new_image" in the image_lib config array.

Comment: That's just for a path to the output file, not what I need.

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason why you shouldn't use `imagecopy` to accomplish this.  The image library in CodeIgniter isn't really set up for what you're trying to do so you'll have to extend it's functionality yourself.